# Nginx configuration for Wordpress running along side Symfony

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, nginx, routes

I have two applications:

- a wordpress site at `/var/www/html/wordpress`
- a symfony application at `/var/www/html/symfony`.

The wordpress application is running as the main domain (`domain.com`).

I want to achieve the following behavior:

- a user visits URL `domain.com/example1`
- nginx redirects to the Symfony route `/example1`.

With my current config nginx already redirects to the Symfony app.

It loads the wordpress site and its admin dashboard correctly.

Issue:

nginx returns the Symfony home page (`/`) instead of `/example1`.

The URLs `domain.com/example1` and `domain.com/example2` loads the Symfony homepage instead of its corresponding route created in the Symfony app.

My nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name domain.com;
    server_tokens off;
    root /var/www/html/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
     client_max_body_size 500M;
#    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        # CUSTOM
        satisfy any;

charset utf-8;
        allow 1.1.1.0/32;
        deny  all;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

### start test

location ^~ /example1 {

      satisfy any;
      allow 1.1.1.0/32;
         deny  all;

      index index.php;
      alias /var/www/html/symfony/current/public/;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
      location ~ \.php$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include fastcgi_params;
      }
 }




location ^~ /example2 {
      satisfy any;
      allow 1.1.1.0/32;
         deny  all;

      index index.php;
      alias /var/www/html/symfony/current/public/;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
      location ~ \.php$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include fastcgi_params;
      }
 }


 location ~ ^((?!\/example1).)*$ { #this regex is to match anything but `/example1`
      satisfy any;
      allow 1.1.1.0/32;
         deny  all;

         index index.php;
         root /var/www/html/wordpress;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$request_uri;
         #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?do=$request_uri;
         location ~ \.php$ {
                 try_files $uri =404;
                 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                 #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                 fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                 fastcgi_index index.php;
                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                 include fastcgi_params;

       }


}



### end test

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

        # CUSTOM
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
```

Comment: Having built such things before I want to ask if you _need_ to do this or _want_ to do this. URL paths that appear to be related to a domain are great for printed or spoken things (visit example.com/offer123 for 10% off) but can be solved with redirects which simplify things greatly, and can often be offloaded to non-technical people. Your Symfony app probably has resources, too, and getting those to pass through can also be troublesome.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly (if not please correct me) , you are suggesting to redirect the wp domain to the symfony domain? I that is the case, it is not possible as it must be the same domain for both projects. We cannot also modify the structure nor any file in the symfony project as it deploys automatically

Comment: What I’m saying is to have example.com and subsite.example.com. One is WordPress, one is Symfony, doesn’t matter which. Have example.com/xyz redirect to subsite.example.com if someone happens to type it in. What I’m asking is about “must be”. I have taken that literally in the past, fought it for years, and finally, once I explained the uphill battles we fought (hosting, PHP versions, development, upgrades, etc.) and offered the split, stakeholders almost always agreed that the redirect would have been fine in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You're potentially overriding the `fastcgi_*` parameters with the defaults in the file `fastcgi_params` after setting them.

Instead of:

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

# the following line loads defaults from file `fastcgi_params`
include fastcgi_params;
```

Move the `include` directive after `fastcgi_pass` and `fastcgi_split_path_info` but before setting `SCRIPT_FILENAME` like this:

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;

include fastcgi_params;

# the following fastcgi_* parameters override the defaults in file `fastcgi_params`
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Comment: We have tried putting the 'include fastcgi_params;' first but then the pages 'domain.com/example1' and 'domain.com/example2' loads a blank page with a 'No input file specified. ' message. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Updated the answer. Try the `include` after the `fastcgi_split_path_info`. See the example in the Symfony documentation: [nginx](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx). Try replacing `$document_root`  with `$realpath_root` and adding `fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;` or hardcode the path to the script as follows `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/index.php`. You can omit `fastcgi_index index.php`.